How to make prod and dev sub folders inside public_html and point the main domain to prod
I have a premium hosting and when I create new website to the main domain , they didn't gave me the option to choose subfolder to the base folder is by default public_html :
/home/u275**1728/domains/si****ie.fr/public_html/

I have created a subdomain dev.sim****ie.fr and I pointed it to sub folder "dev" successfully because they gave me the option to make sub folder
/home/u275**1728/domains/sim****ie.fr/public_html/dev

Now how can I point the main domain to a sub directory "prod" like so ?
/home/u275**1728/domains/sim****ie.fr/public_html/prod


You can rewrite incoming requests according to the requested host name ("domain"). You will find many existing answers here on SO for such thing.

Just a side note however: usually one does not operate a production and a development version in the same environment. Consider setting up a local development environment. That allows you much more control and minimizes your dependency on network, internet, the provider and and and

@arkascha , I work on local then I send the modifications to dev on the server to do tests and the client test it before. If it's ok I pull it in prod. In fact the dev is only for tests not for developpement

Sounds fine to me then ;-) So "dev" actually is "staging". And I assume it is a clone of your git repository, so that "send the modification" means a push and a pull to a repository server.
